# Sum of second value in nested list by first value using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python

```
x = [(5, 65),
 (2, 12),
 (5, 18),
 (3, 35),
 (4, 49),
 (4, 10),
 (1, 27),
 (1, 1),
 (4, 71),
 (2, 41),
 (2, 17),
 (1, 25),
 (2, 62),
 (5, 65),
 (4, 5),
 (1, 51),
 (1, 13),
 (5, 92),
 (2, 62),
 (5, 81)]
```

I have this list of nested tuples and I want to sum up the second value by the first value. Since there are 5 values currently in the first column, I would get 5 values returned, which would be the sum of the second value in each record where the first value matched.

The output I'm looking for is something like [117, 194, 35, 135, 321]. This is ordered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but I honestly don't even need it to be in order I just need a list of the sums.

I'm trying to accomplish this using list comprehension in Python since I've been learning about it and I'm struggling with this example.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “sum up the second value by the first value”, by updating the question.

Comment: This look simpler to use a dictionary whose keys are the first item of your lists.

Comment: Sounds like you want to sum the second values in all tuples whose first values match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using just list comprehension:

```
x = [(5, 65),
     (2, 12),
     (5, 18),
     (3, 35),
     (4, 49),
     (4, 10),
     (1, 27),
     (1, 1),
     (4, 71),
     (2, 41),
     (2, 17),
     (1, 25),
     (2, 62),
     (5, 65),
     (4, 5),
     (1, 51),
     (1, 13),
     (5, 92),
     (2, 62),
     (5, 81)]


key_range = set([k for k, _ in x])
res = [sum([v for k, v in x if k == i]) for i in key_range]
```

Comment: You don't need to build a list inside a call to `sum()`, you can pass a generator expression directly.

Comment: Nice but you lose the linear complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Using `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(x)
>>> df.groupby(0).sum()[1].tolist()
[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> keys, values = map(iter, zip(*sorted(x)))
>>> [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(values, lambda _: next(keys))]
[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary:

```py
d = dict()
for i, val in x:
   d.setdefault(i , 0)
   d[i] += val
result = list(d.items())
```

Comment: A variant on this solution can be to use defaultdict

Answer (score 1):

If you need them sorted, then use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

x = [(5, 65), (2, 12), (5, 18), (3, 35), (4, 49), (4, 10), (1, 27), (1, 1), (4, 71), (2, 41),
     (2, 17), (1, 25), (2, 62), (5, 65), (4, 5), (1, 51), (1, 13), (5, 92), (2, 62), (5, 81)]


result = [sum(v for _, v in value) for key, value in groupby(sorted(x), key=itemgetter(0))]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```

But the above approach is not very efficient, so I suggest you could use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [(5, 65), (2, 12), (5, 18), (3, 35), (4, 49), (4, 10), (1, 27), (1, 1), (4, 71), (2, 41),
     (2, 17), (1, 25), (2, 62), (5, 65), (4, 5), (1, 51), (1, 13), (5, 92), (2, 62), (5, 81)]


counts = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in x:
    counts[key] += value

result = [v for _, v in sorted(counts.items())]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```

As a rule of thumb when you are dealing with values that need to reduce or accumulated by a key using a list comprehension may not be the most efficient approach.

**Note**

The most efficient approach that fits **your example and only your example** (small numbers of keys in a small range [1, 5]) is to simply do:

```
result = [0 for _ in range(5)]
for key, value in x:
    result[key - 1] += value

print(result)
```

Comment: conversely "The output I'm looking for is something like [117, 194, 35, 135, 321]. This is ordered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but I honestly don't even need it to be in order I just need a list of the sums." so you can avoid the call to `items` and just use `values`

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but if you want it in a list comprehension, you can do it like this:

```
[ sum(n for k,n in x if k==K) for K in range(1,6) ]

[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```

A for-loop on the list of tuples to "pigeonhole" the additions in a list of sums would be more efficient:

```
sums = [0]*5
for k,n in x: sums[k-1] += n
                
[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```