# Efficiently slice iterable by another iterable

Tags: python

So I'm trying to slice an iterable to the same length of another iterable. For context I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69530024/225020) to get the sum of values grouped by key *essentially* and I think I can do this more efficiently

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [(5, 65), (2, 12), (5, 18), (3, 35), (4, 49), (4, 10), (1, 27), (1, 1), (4, 71), (2, 41), (2, 17), (1, 25), (2, 62), (5, 65), (4, 5), (1, 51), (1, 13), (5, 92), (2, 62), (5, 81)]

keys, values = map(iter, zip(*sorted(x)))
print([sum(next(values) for _ in g) for _, g in groupby(keys)])
#[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```

I believe the `next(values) for _ in g` can be done functionally or more concisely. Essentially in pseudocode:

```
#from this
sum(next(values) for _ in g)
#to this
sum(values[length of g])
```

I know the above won't work but all I can think of is using `zip` because it only iterates to the end of the smallest iterable. Although, when I tried that it's consuming more than the group is long. *(Also it isn't very readable)* See below what I tried:

```
print([sum(next(zip(*zip(values, g)))) for _, g in groupby(keys)])
#[117, 217, 10, 219, 92]
```

I've tried searching for this with no results unless I'm not searching the right thing.

I've thought of other solutions such as using islice but I would need the length of `g` and thats another messy solution. Another being I could just use `operator.itemgetter` but if I could figure out how to do what I am doing more concisely then maybe I can use it in other solutions too.

Comment: What exactly is the output you expect? It might be in the text, but it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Basically I am using groupby on the tuples first values. I want to use those groups to slice `values` and sum that slice.

Comment: If you replace `sum` in my code with `tuple` or `list` you will see where the discrepancy lies. The first snippet is correctly running code although the second is not performing as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to separate the keys and values at all. It can be handled by the key functions:

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig

[sum(map(ig(1), g)) for _, g in groupby(sorted(x), key=ig(0))]
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using `itemgetter` I should have specified that in my question. Reason being I don't think that is the most concise way solution.

Comment: I don't think you are right here. After all, your original data is has keys and values already aligned. Separating them and rezipping cannot be the best approach. Also, `itemgetter` is C-optimized and should not be a reason for performance concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ilen` from more-itertools and then `islice`:

```
[sum(islice(values, ilen(g))) for _, g in groupby(keys)]
```

Or with `zip`, but the group first:

```
[sum(x for _, x in zip(g, values)) for _, g in groupby(keys)]
```

Don't know how "efficient" these are for you, as you only showed very small data and I'm not sure how you'd generalize it (in particular, how long your groups are).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are asking can be accomplished by the following class. The class `groupby_other` takes an iterable `it1` and an iterable of iterables `it2`: `it2_0, it2_1, ...` and yields groups of  elements from `it1` with lengths equal to `it2_0`, `it2_1` and so on, until one of `it1` or `it2` is exhausted.

```py
class groupby_other:
    """
    Make an iterator that returns groups from iterable1. Each group has the same
    number of elements as each element in iterable2.

    >>> y = [1,2,3,4,5]
    >>> z = [[1,1], [4,4,4]]
    >>> [list(x) for x in groupby_other(y,z)]
    [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

    Grouping is terminated when one of the iterables is exhausted

    >>> y = [1,2,3,4,5]
    >>> z = [[1,1], [4,4,4], [4,5]]
    >>> [list(x) for x in groupby_other(y,z)]
    [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
    >>> z = [[1,1], [4,4,4]]
    >>> [list(x) for x in groupby_other(y,z)]
    [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
    >>> z = [[1,1], [4,4]]
    >>> [list(x) for x in groupby_other(y,z)]
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    >>> [list(x) for x in groupby_other([],z)]
    []
    >>> [list(x) for x in groupby_other(y,[])]
    []

    """
    def __init__(self, iterable1, iterable2, key=None):
        self.it1 = iter(iterable1)
        self.it2 = iter(iterable2)
        self.current_it = None
        self.done = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.done:
            raise StopIteration
        current_group = iter(next(self.it2))    # Exit on StopIteration
        current_item = next(self.it1)
        return self._grouper(current_item, current_group)

    def _grouper(self, current_item, current_group):
        try:
            next(current_group)
            yield current_item
            for _ in current_group:
                yield next(self.it1)
        except StopIteration:
            self.done=True
            return
```

Then you can do:

```py
>>> [sum(x) for x in groupby_other(values, (g for _, g in groupby(keys)))]
[117, 194, 35, 135, 321]
```